# Custom module shows in list but not in permissions

Tags: 7, users

I have a simple module I created and it shows up in modules config panel and I have enabled it. The functions are called and the output even shows:

```
function products_help($path, $arg) {
  if ($path == 'admin/help#first') {
    return t('Products Help');
  }
}

function products_perm() {
  return array(
    'access products' => array(
      'title' => t('TBYT Products'),
      'description' => t('Administer TBYT Products'),
    )
  );
}

function products_menu() {
  $items = array();

  $items['products/winnipeg'] = array(
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,

    'title' => 'Enjoy shopping in Winnipeg',
    'page callback' => 'list_products',
    'access arguments' => array('access products')
  );

  return $items;
}
```

What am I missing? I cannot find this module anywhere under permission configuration...I expect to find the option for allowing "access products" to authenticated user???

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You missed this one**

```
'access callback' => 'user_access',
```

If you give this one in the `hook_menu` then it will show in the permissions tab.

[Updated Answer]

`Hook_permission()` will allow you to create a permission string in the permission tab.

```
    function hook_permission() {
  return array(
    'string' => array(
      'title' => t('Administer my module'),
    ),
  );
```

}

Comment: The access callback is "user_access" by default, so simply providing an array of permissions is enough in this case.

Comment: Your example hook implementation is incorrect. The return value of the array needs to have a title key.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement [hook_permission](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_permission/7) to register any custom permissions that your module exposes.

Once you have implemented this hook you can then use your new permission in `user_access` or `hook_menu`.

Comment: Ooooh so it's renamed in D7???

Comment: Yep, from hook_perm I believe. Why it was ever called hook_perm is beyond me. http://i.imgur.com/W1jzJb7.jpg